# knitr - knit one chunk only?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm wondering if there is a way to selectively knit and output one chunk only of an R markdown file?
I sometimes add an analysis for a client some time later and it would be nice to just output that part of the analysis to a html file without including everything (or setting eval=F in every other chunk).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add global chunk options using this code:

````
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval=FALSE)
```
````

As explained in further detail here: http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/Rmarkdown.html